# Check status of content type subscriber timer job

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type-hub

We have a SP Online environment with a content type hub to handle all content types. I know that new and changed CT's are (re)published every time the content type subscriber timer job runs.
However I don't know how often it runs since we didn't set this up ourselves. I do believe it's every hour, but I'm not sure.
Is there a way for me to see when the last run of the job was? And can I check the setting somewhere or can it not be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Office 365, we don’t have the direct control over the timer jobs. Hence, we need to wait for certain duration until Microsoft runs the timer job.

There is no official article which indicates how often content type subscriber runs in SharePoint online. There is an article says that it may take up to about 4 hours.

https://sandyu.com/2016/11/19/using-the-sharepoint-online-content-type-hub/

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks for the confirmation though!